# New page per a group in crystal report

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports

I'd like to show new page per a group in crystal report. Please check my images below

report design[image: report design]

report review[image: report review]

How to set to show one group box per page?

Comment: What point is there in including the MS-ACCESS tag here?

Comment: I just describe the developing environment.

Comment: But there's nothing about Access mentioned in your question. My feeling is that tags should NEVER mention technologies/subjects that are not part of the actual problem being asked about. Certainly the tangential environment can be mentioned in the question itself, but for tags, it's just not useful, as the question has NOTHING to do with Access at all -- not even one little bit.

Comment: David, I removed MS-ACCESS. Always welcome to any suggestion because I'm a newbie at Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In GroupFooterSection1, set the property NewPageAfter to Always.

Comment: I set it in Section expert. It doesn't show the whole group box per page.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You set the NewPageAfter property in Section expert? Where are you getting a new page - after the Details section?

Comment: Now, it works. Previously, I wrongly set it at GroupHeaderSection1. Thank you.

Comment: Steve, I got one extra page at the end. How to remove it?

Comment: I got it. I set "Not OnLastRecord" in NewPageAfter Property.

Comment: This saves my day